# How to configure custom ethereum node in foundry project?

Tags: hardhat, testing, ganache, foundry

Hardhat allows users to configure a custom network in the [networks configuration object](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#networks-configuration). This allows developers to run their JS/TS test suites against another local node such as Ganache or even a live network such as an Ethereum testnet.

Can this be done in Foundry as well? For example, instead of using Foundry's default node [Anvil](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/anvil) users can specify a locally running node such as a hardhat or ganache local node that they want to run their Foundry project's test suites(written in solidity) on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Foundry allows users to configure custom Ethereum nodes.

##### RPC-Endpoints settings

[Custom RPC endpoints](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/crates/config#rpc-endpoints-settings) can be defined in the `foundry.toml` under `[rpc_endpoints]` as follows:

```
# foundry.toml

[rpc_endpoints]
  optimism = "https://optimism.alchemyapi.io/v2/1234567" # since the foundry.toml is commited it's not recommened to have the api key explicitly
  mainnet = "${RPC_MAINNET}" # it's recommened to do either this
  goerli = "https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}" # or this
```

##### Forge Commands

forge commands typically have a flag that allows you to run various commands with specified network configurations using either an explicit RPC URL or a network alias defined in the `foundry.toml`

**Testing with a Forked Environment:**

`--rpc-url`, `--fork-url` and `-f` are valid options for [forge test](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-test#evm-options)

```bash
forge test --fork-url <rpc_url_or_alias>
```

**Deploying contracts to a network**

`--rpc-url` is a valid option for [forge create](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-create#rpc-options)

```bash
forge create --rpc-url <rpc_url_or_alias> --private-key <your_private_key> src/MyContract.sol:MyContract
```

**Running solidity scripts against a network**

`--rpc-url`, `--fork-url` and `-f` are valid options for [forge script](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-script#evm-options)

```bash
forge script --rpc-url <rpc_url_or_alias> --fork-block-number <block_number> path [args...]
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it can be done, if you spin your local hardhat node, you can then run your tests like:

```
forge test --fork-url http://127.0.0.1:8545 -vv --match-test testYOURTEST
```

where [http://127.0.0.1:8545`](http://127.0.0.1:8545%60) refers to your hardhat node. Or in case you want to fork ethereum mainnet, then your mainnet RPC

Hope it helps